# Side effect with the Alfresco content repository API?

Tags: java, api, repository, server-side, alfresco

I'm studying Alfresco and particularly it's content repository Java API.

I am trying to train with an example from the SDK "First Foundation Client".

I took the code, I manage to handle it a bit but when I restart my alfresco server I get ugly stacktrace like

```
ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03130001 Failed to initialise org.alfresco.enterprise.license.LicenseComponent
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.constructSpecialService(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:301)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.access$100(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:51)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl$1$1.execute(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:181)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl$1$1.execute(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:327)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl$1.doWork(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:175)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:514)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.onBootstrap(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:168)
    at org.alfresco.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:77)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:246)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:355)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:627)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1149)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.constructSpecialService(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:286)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.NodePropertyValue.getValue(NodePropertyValue.java:986)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.hibernate.HibernateNodeDaoServiceImpl.makeSerializableValue(HibernateNodeDaoServiceImpl.java:5371)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.hibernate.HibernateNodeDaoServiceImpl.collapsePropertiesWithSameQNameAndListIndex(HibernateNodeDaoServiceImpl.java:5313)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.hibernate.HibernateNodeDaoServiceImpl.convertToPublicProperties(HibernateNodeDaoServiceImpl.java:5155)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.hibernate.HibernateNodeDaoServiceImpl.getNodeProperties(HibernateNodeDaoServiceImpl.java:1424)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:304)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.TransactionalDaoInterceptor.invoke(TransactionalDaoInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.hibernate.DirtySessionMethodInterceptor.invoke(DirtySessionMethodInterceptor.java:419)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.SingleEntryTransactionResourceInterceptor.invokeInternal(SingleEntryTransactionResourceInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.SingleEntryTransactionResourceInterceptor.invoke(SingleEntryTransactionResourceInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy9.getNodeProperties(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.getPropertiesImpl(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:1292)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.getProperties(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:1283)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:304)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.MultiTNodeServiceInterceptor.invoke(MultiTNodeServiceInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy11.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.alfresco.repo.service.StoreRedirectorProxyFactory$RedirectorInvocationHandler.invoke(StoreRedirectorProxyFactory.java:221)
    at $Proxy12.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:304)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.invoke(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.invoke(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.invoke(NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.invoke(NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy11.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.RepositoryDescriptorDAOImpl.getDescriptor(RepositoryDescriptorDAOImpl.java:178)
    at org.alfresco.enterprise.license.LicenseComponent.<init>(LicenseComponent.java:99)
    ... 47 more
```

I precise that I don't get this problem when I quit my alfresco and restart it as long as I don't run my code while the server is stopped. !!!

Is this a known issue ? Google is not very chatty about it (may be it's me that cant make him talk)...

I work with **Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala**

I've an official JDK **jdk1.6.0_14**

and **alfresco 3.2r Enterprise** for the server

`EDIT reason='add'`

and **alfresco-community-sdk-3.3** for the SDK

I ran other tests (and the results ain't pretty) :
- The original example runs well but crashes my server
- Running a "Daguerre investigation" I removed all the lines to find out that the fail is implied by

```
ApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext();
```

Which is the backbone of the API use ...

If anyone has any idea ...

Comment: You might find it easier to use CMIS to connect to the repository to store and retrieve your documents. See http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS for details on what CMIS is, and how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Add the end of you code do you do a `System.exit(0);`

This is what I get from the Enterprise SDK sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // initialise app content 
        ApplicationContext ctx = ApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext();
        // get registry of services
        final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) ctx.getBean(ServiceRegistry.SERVICE_REGISTRY);

        // use TransactionWork to wrap service calls in a user transaction
        TransactionService transactionService = serviceRegistry.getTransactionService();
        RetryingTransactionCallback<Object> exampleWork = new RetryingTransactionCallback<Object>()
        {
            public Object execute() throws Exception
            {
                doExample(serviceRegistry);
                return null;
            }
        };
        transactionService.getRetryingTransactionHelper().doInTransaction(exampleWork);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```